# OneToOne custom join query

Tags: java, hibernate, join, one-to-one

I want to have custom join query for OneToOne relationships. I need to add one more clause to where part, because without it I get `More than one row with the given identifier was found: com.example.Container_$$_javassist_0@17156065, for class: com.example.AnyContainer` Is it possible to do that?

Container.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "container")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Container implements Serializable {

    private String oid;
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ContainerIdGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "ContainerIdGenerator", strategy = "com.example.ContainerIdGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "OidGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "OidGenerator", strategy = "com.example.OidGenerator")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 36)
    public String getOid() {
        return oid;
    }
    ..other getters/setters
}
```

O.java: Hibernate will use `select c.ownerType, c.owner_oid, c.owner_id from any c where c.owner_oid=? and c.owner_id=?` query but here I want to use something like this `from AnyContainer as c where c.owner = ? and c.ownerType = 0` for as join query. and for ? there should be owner as usual. I added there one more condition -> `ownerType = 0`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "object")
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_container")
public abstract class O extends Container {

    private AnyContainer extension;

    @OneToOne(optional = true, mappedBy = "owner")
    @ForeignKey(name = "none")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    public AnyContainer getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }
    ...other getters/setters
}
```

ResourceObjectShadow.java: Hibernate will use `select c.ownerType, c.owner_oid, c.owner_id from any c where c.owner_oid=? and c.owner_id=?` query but here I want to use something like this `from AnyContainer as c where c.owner = ? and c.ownerType = 1` for as join query. and for ? there should be owner as usual.  I added there one more condition -> `ownerType = 1`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "resource_shadow")
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_resource_object_shadow")
public class ResourceObjectShadow extends O {

    private AnyContainer attributes;

    @OneToOne(optional = true, mappedBy = "owner")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    public AnyContainer getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }
    ...other getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "any")
public class AnyContainer implements Serializable {

    private RContainerType ownerType;
    private Container owner;

    @ForeignKey(name = "fk_reference_owner")
    @MapsId("owner")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "owner_oid", referencedColumnName = "ownerOid"),
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    })
    public Container getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    ..other getters/setters
}
```

RContainerType.java

```
public enum RContainerType {   
    O, RESOURCE_OBJECT_SHADOW
}
```

Edit: Updated `ManyToOne` -> to `OneToOne` in `AnyContainer`
I tried to user `@Loader` with named query annotated on class `O` and `ResourceObjectShadow`, but it wasn't used. Also I tried only as test to use it on `AnyContainer` class, but wasn't used at all.

How to handle custom join for that `OneToOne` relationship in `O` and `ResourceObjectShadow`? Is there way to do it programmatically (for example through custom tuplizer or something like that)?

Answer (score 0):

When you want join based on multiple columns you can use the `with` operator in **HQL**

```
from AnyBean as a join a.b with b.type = 0
```

Now if you want to create a mapping like this, you can use the `formula` tag.

```
<one-to-one name="one2oneSubRef"
class="com.manu.hibernate.mappings.domain.RefOnlyAMain" property-ref="parentARef"
             cascade="all" >

<formula>'A'</formula>

<formula>a_id</formula>

</one-to-one>
```

This mapping will always join the table based on two columns.

Read an example [here](http://www.jyops.blogspot.in/2011/03/hibernate-mapping-example.html) or the API Docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-property).

Comment: I tried to add `@Formula("..some hql..")` to `O.extension` mapping, but it's was not used as I want, `AnyContainer` was still searched only through `owner_oid` and `owner_id`, `ownerType` was not used. Can @OneToOne annotation be removed and somehow this relationship mapped programmatically through some Tuplizer or something like that?

Comment: I could not find any examples with the annotation, see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334676/hibernate-many-to-one-using-formula) helps.